# How to change css style of Kendo Combobox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css

I am using `Kendo ComboBox` in my `MVC application`.
but the Default style for `ComboBox` is like this.
[image]

I would like to modify style given in above red box.
So which `css class` i need to change for this modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code in your css file:

```
.k-select{
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

See result here:

http://jsfiddle.net/lin/euQF8/191/